# Does the sentence containing "I’ve done made" make sense?

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-perfect, past-participles, objects

> I’ve done made a black tea with a slice of lime on it .

it appeared in a group chat that include many non-English native speakers and seems odd to me.

since "done" can be a transitive verb, that means it can have an object.

but "made a black tea " doesn't seem to be an object of "done".

Is "made a black tea" the object? or does "made" contribute to the perfect aspect?

Answer (score 2):

This use of "done" (the "perfective done") is common in dialects like [African-American Vernacular English (AAVE)](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/perfective-done) and in various idioms derived from those dialects. It serves primarily as a marker of the perfect aspect, but in this sentence that would be redundant, since the "have" in "I've" already makes it perfect. But the "perfective done" usually also implies that the action was *recent,* which is its function here. So the meaning is:

> I’ve **just** made a black tea with a slice of lime on it.

(Alternatively, if this was from a non-native speaker, it could just be a mistake, likely the result of an attempt to add do-support to a verb that already has an auxiliary.)

Comment: Is "made a black tea" the object?
or does "made" contribute to the perfect aspect?

Comment: No, because "done" isn't a verb. In standard English "done" is the past participle form of the verb "do".  It has an additional adverbal sense in AAV.  The verb is "made".  But I think this is more likely to be a simple mistake by a non-native speaker, which only co-incidentally fits an AAV idiom.

Comment: Also "on it" seems odd, since normally the lime would be in the tea.

Comment: In this use in AAVE, "done" is an auxiliary verb.